# subdomains issue

Tags: apache-2.2, subdomain

I have created subdomains for my main site.

like

- cdn1.abc.com
- cdn2.abc.com
- cdn3.abc.com

and all point to / . but when I try to use cdn1.abc.com in a url it does not work. Perchance there is  something else I need to do?

Comment: What are you using to manage your subdomains?

Comment: and which web server?

Comment: @Eric Petroelje - apache server and godaddy account

Answer (score 3):

With your virtual host settings, you need to add a ServerAlias, sort of like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName abc.com
        ServerAlias cdn1.abc.com cdn2.abc.com cdn3.abc.com
```

You could also do "*.abc.com" on that line instead, if you wanted to allow all subdomains.

Answer (score 1):

You need to setup Apache to serve your files for all of the subdomains.

Comment: @SLaks  - it says Server not found error

Comment: @SLaks  - godaddy provides a interface to create subdomains. then also i need to do apache configuration.. can u just show me the apache code for it?

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts to this:

- You must create the DNS records so that those new names resolve to the IP address of your server.  That will allow people to get sent to the correct location.
- The second part is configuring Apache to recognize these new hostnames and serve the right content.

The first part will probably involve you using some online control-panel at your domain registrar.  The second part will probably be as simple as adding:

```
 ...
 ServerName abc.com
 ServerAlias     cdn1.abc.com cdn2.abc.com cdn3.abc.com
```

then restarting apache2.